# SharedSizeGroup in menuItem template

Tags: wpf, xaml, alignment, controltemplate

I have to apply a specific design to my application's menus.

So I took Microsoft's template example as a basis to build on:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms747082.aspx

so what I did is I created a new ResourceDictionary containing all those templates/Brushes/Styles etc... (just copy/pasted them) in my app's resources.

it works pretty well except for ONE thing:

the SharedSizeGroup property seems to have no effect whatsoever. The icons/checkmarks are not at all aligned, and if I have a menuItem with an icon followed by a menuItem with no icon, the one without icon will be left-aligned, so that it starts below the first one's icon. (ugly)

now I read the doc and one part has me stuck :

> Grid size-sharing does not work if you
>   set IsSharedSizeScope to true within a
>   resource template and you define
>   SharedSizeGroup as outside that
>   template.

what on earth does that mean? and is it (as I suspect) the source of my problem here. If yes, what is the solution?

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied these from Blend 4 and tried them out and they seem to be working ok. You'll need a reference to PresentationFramework.Aero

```
xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuItemSelectionFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#34C5EBFF" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#3481D8FF" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<Geometry x:Key="Checkmark">M 0,5.1 L 1.7,5.2 L 3.4,7.1 L 8,0.4 L 9.2,0 L 3.3,10.8 Z</Geometry>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <Rectangle x:Name="Bg" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="InnerBorder" Margin="1" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2"/>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="24" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="37"/>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" Margin="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="#CDD3E6" BorderThickness="1" Background="#E6EFF4" CornerRadius="3" Height="22" Margin="1" Visibility="Hidden" Width="22">
                <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Fill="#0C12A1" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="11" Width="9"/>
            </Border>
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemSelectionFill}"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bg" Value="#8071CBF1"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#40FFFFFF"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF9A9A9A"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#EEE9E9"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#DBD6D6"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="#848589"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuItemPressedFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#28717070" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#50717070" Offset="0.75"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#90717070" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SubMenuBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF5F5F5"/>
<Geometry x:Key="UpArrow">M 0,4 L 3.5,0 L 7,4 Z</Geometry>
<Style x:Key="MenuScrollButton" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Hover"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <DockPanel Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="R1" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Fill="Transparent" Width="1"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="B1" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Fill="Transparent" Height="1"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="L1" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Fill="Transparent" Width="1"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="T1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Fill="Transparent" Height="1"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,2,2,2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DockPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="R1" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="B1" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="L1" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="T1" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="ContentContainer" Value="3,3,1,1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter x:Key="MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter"/>
<Geometry x:Key="DownArrow">M 0,0 L 3.5,4 L 7,0 Z</Geometry>
<Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                        <ScrollContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <RepeatButton Grid.Column="0" CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}" Focusable="false" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource MenuScrollButton}">
                        <RepeatButton.Visibility>
                            <MultiBinding ConverterParameter="0" Converter="{StaticResource MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter}" FallbackValue="Visibility.Collapsed">
                                <Binding Path="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                <Binding Path="VerticalOffset" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                <Binding Path="ExtentHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                <Binding Path="ViewportHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </RepeatButton.Visibility>
                        <Path Data="{StaticResource UpArrow}" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </RepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Grid.Column="0" CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineDownCommand}" Focusable="false" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource MenuScrollButton}">
                        <RepeatButton.Visibility>
                            <MultiBinding ConverterParameter="100" Converter="{StaticResource MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter}" FallbackValue="Visibility.Collapsed">
                                <Binding Path="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                <Binding Path="VerticalOffset" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                <Binding Path="ExtentHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                <Binding Path="ViewportHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </RepeatButton.Visibility>
                        <Path Data="{StaticResource DownArrow}" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </RepeatButton>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuContent, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Border BorderBrush="#FF959595" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource SubMenuBackgroundBrush}">
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Fill="#F1F1F1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Width="28"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="#E2E3E3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,2,0,2" Width="1"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,2,0,2" Width="1"/>
            <ContentPresenter Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="1,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <Rectangle x:Name="OuterBorder" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Bg" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="1" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="InnerBorder" Margin="2"/>
        <DockPanel>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" Margin="4,0,6,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="7,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" HorizontalOffset="1" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom" VerticalOffset="-1">
            <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent">
                <ContentControl x:Name="SubMenuBorder" IsTabStop="false" Template="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuContent, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" CanContentScroll="true" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                        <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource SubMenuBackgroundBrush}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ContentControl>
            </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
            <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bg" Value="#90717070"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="#50FFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#50FFFFFF"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bg" Value="#E0717070"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemPressedFill}"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#50747272"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bg" Value="#E0717070"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemPressedFill}"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#50747272"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF9A9A9A"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#848589"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <Rectangle x:Name="OuterBorder" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Bg" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="1" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="InnerBorder" Margin="2"/>
        <DockPanel>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" Margin="4,0,6,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="7,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bg" Value="#90717070"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="#50FFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#50FFFFFF"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bg" Value="#E0717070"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemPressedFill}"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#50747272"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF9A9A9A"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#848589"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
<Geometry x:Key="RightArrow">M 0,0 L 4,3.5 L 0,7 Z</Geometry>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <Rectangle x:Name="Bg" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="InnerBorder" Margin="1" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="Transparent" StrokeThickness="1"/>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="24" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="37"/>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" Margin="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="#CDD3E6" BorderThickness="1" Background="#E6EFF4" CornerRadius="3" Height="22" Margin="1" Visibility="Hidden" Width="22">
                <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Fill="#0C12A1" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="11" Width="9"/>
            </Border>
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <Path Grid.Column="5" Data="{StaticResource RightArrow}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" HorizontalOffset="-2" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Right" VerticalOffset="-3">
            <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent">
                <ContentControl x:Name="SubMenuBorder" IsTabStop="false" Template="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuContent, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" CanContentScroll="true" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                        <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource SubMenuBackgroundBrush}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ContentControl>
            </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#D1DBF4FF"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
            <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemSelectionFill}"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bg" Value="#8571CBF1"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF9A9A9A"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#EEE9E9"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#DBD6D6"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="#848589"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7,2,8,3"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7,2,8,3"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,3,2,3"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,3,2,3"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: not quite the answer I was looking for, BUT... it helped me find the problem. apparently, the Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" was ignored where it was (in the original template). After I put it in the same place as in the code you pasted (i.e: in the itemsPresenter in the TopLevelHeader Template), it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: @David: Glad it helped you find it :) I've had problems with the templates/styles from msdn before so I never use them anymore, I use Blend instead. If you don't have Blend installed that's not an option though.

Comment: I have it installed, but I never really used it to get te original templates (I don't like getting references to the aero them). I'll have to have a look though, if it helps me figure out stuff like this...

Comment: Setting `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` on the `StackPanel` on the `MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey` `ControlTemplate` will make this work, as the StackPanel is the parent rendering the MenuItem Grid's.